# SQL: Need to find duplicate rows across multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I've tried using other solutions I've found, but none have worked. I have a table with four columns, Supplier, ProductCode, Description, and Price. The Supplier field is linked to another table with a list of suppliers. I need to find any records that have the exact same Supplier and ProductCode. Thanks in advance!!

I copied this code from another thread and tried to modify it for my table, but I get errors:

```
SELECT s.id, t.*
FROM ListPrices AS s
JOIN (SELECT Supplier, ProductCode, count(*) AS qty
FROM ListPrices GROUP BY Supplier, [ProductCode] HAVING count(*) > 1) 
AS t ON (s.ProductCode = t.ProductCode) AND (s.Supplier = t.Supplier);
```

Comment: Hi there, can you show us what you have done?

Comment: You can do this with a self-`Join` on the Supplier and ProductCode. But do you have anything like an `Id` field that can distinguish the individual rows?

Comment: I'd usually use `EXISTS` to do this, but all of my tables have a unique ID column so I can distinguish between any that might have the same values.

Comment: SELECT Supplier, ProductCode, COUNT( *) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Supplier, ProductCode HAVING COUNT( *) > 1 ??

Comment: Richard: I tried that, but it actually gives me back things without exact duplicates in both fields.

Comment: Siyual: I do, but I'm trying to create a composite primary key, but Access thinks I have duplicate data in my table which I have to find and get rid of

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you are looking for but one way to do this is to group by supplier and productcode and  check if the count > 1

```
   select * from (
   select supplier,productcode,count(*) as count_rows 
   from listprices group by supplier,productcode) inner_table
   where inner_table.count_rows > 1;
```

Comment: I have the same issue with this, it still returns records that are not actually duplicates...No idea why that would be